# Swagger Docs index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, swagger, rails-api, json-api

My swagger index DSL is responding with the `api/v1/users.json` generated from `rake swagger:docs`.

`Api::V1::UsersController`:

```
  swagger_api :index do
    summary 'Returns list of users'
    notes '/api/v1/users'
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render(json: { users: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@users, each_serializer: Api::V1::UserSerializer) })
  end
```

---

And when I try go the the actual api documentation and run `/api/v1/users.json` call ("Try it out!"), I get the public api definition for the whole users api controller:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://localhost:3000",
  "resourcePath": "users",
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "/api/v1/users.json",
      "operations": [
        {
          "summary": "Returns list of users",
          "notes": "/api/v1/users",
          "nickname": "Api::V1::Users#index",
          "method": "get"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/api/v1/users/{id}.json",
      "operations": [
        {
          "summary": "Returns a user",
          "notes": "/api/v1/users/:id",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "paramType": "path",
              "name": "id",
              "type": "integer",
              "description": "User Id",
              "required": false
            }
          ],
          "nickname": "Api::V1::Users#show",
          "method": "get"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "authorizations": null
}
```

Also, when I try the call in Postman, it returns an array of Users like I would expect.